# Cannot use DataBinder on a hibernate object in the http session

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a session attribute, myForm contains some Hibernate objects loaded from the DB

```
@SessionAttributes("myForm")
```

From my controller I receive the form and process it like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mymapping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public final JsonValidationResponse validateContact(
        @ModelAttribute(value = "myForm") final MyForm myForm) {

    return jsonValidator.getJsonErrors(myForm.getContact());

}
```

The Contact class has the following validation annotation

```
@Email
private String email;
```

The following method is having the problem

```
    public final <T> JsonValidationResponse getJsonErrors(
            final T objectToValidate) {

        //TEST CODE HERE   

        DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(objectToValidate);
        binder.setValidator(validator);
        binder.validate();
        return getJsonErrors(binder.getBindingResult());
    }
```

If I observe objectToValidate I see following, I think this is because it is a hibernate object and is using LAZY initialisation.

> com.mypackage.Contact_$$_javassist_27@1bdbbc0[contactId=0,name=,email=,phone1=,phone2=,phone3=,version=0,createDate=,modifiedDate=,userId=]

If I run a gettter on objectToValidate at `//TEST CODE HERE` like below, I get the correct value passed in ('dummy' for example), if after running this I observe 'objectToValidate' again it displays the same result as above even though it should now be no longer Lazy initialized.

```
String email = (Contact)objectToValidate.getEmail();
```

If I create a dummy object at `//TEST CODE HERE`, the code works fine and the binder finds errors.

```
    Contact dummy = new Contact();
    dummy.setEmail("dummy");
```

Basically binder.getBindingResult() does not when using the hibernate object and I don't know how to fix it.  It appears that it is not able to resolve the hibernate object properties that are LAZY initialised (even after I call a method on the object and get the correct result).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using lazy initialization then hibernate has to use proxies. That means that `objectToValidate` is not the 'real' object, it just behaves like it.

In your case validation takes place at the field level. After all you have annotated the field `email` not the property `getEmail()`.

While I cannot say what exactly is going on in your case I can say that is has to do with the discrepancy between accessing a proxy and directly accessing a field. I suggest either to annotate the property or not to use lazy initialization.